# How to increase cobertura Score

Tags: model-view-controller, spring

Hello friends I am new here Please Don't mind if i ask very easy question.

I am working on Spring 3.0  and i am using cobertura to check my code coverage.

Although all my test cases are successful i can't get full coverage due to error blocks.

Can anyone help how to cover the blocks marked in Red.

Thanks in advance.

```
//This Code is For SQL Map of DAO

@SuppressWarnings(ApplicationConstants.UNCHECKED) 
@Override 
public List<ReportListDTO> searchGeneralReport(
        final ReportSearch reportSearch) throws COBException { 
    List<ReportListDTO> generalSearchList; 
    try{ 
        generalSearchList = this.sqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(
                "cobSQLReportQuery.searchGeneralReport",reportSearch); 
    }catch(DataAccessException dae){ 
        // NOT COVERED BY COBERTURA
        throw new COBException(this.getClass().getName() 
                + "SQL Exception in COB DB Operation",dae);
    } 
    LOGGER.info("TableSize Coming From DB"+generalSearchList.size()); 
    return generalSearchList; 
}
```

Can anyone help me to get code coverage for highlighted lines?

```
//This Code For Controller
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = ApplicationConstants.GENERAL_REPORT_SEARCH) 
public ModelAndView searchGeneralReport(
        final @ModelAttribute(ApplicationConstants.GENERAL_REPORT_COMMAND) ReportSearch reportSearch, 
        final BindingResult result) throws COBException { 

    final String[] mainSearchG = StringUtils.split(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_SEARCH_CRITERIA,","); 
    final String[] mainSearchV = StringUtils.split(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_SEARCH_CRITERIA_VALUES,","); 
    final String[] daysOutstanding= StringUtils.split(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_DAYS_OUTSTANDING,","); 
    //Splitting LookUp's 
    final List<LookUpValueBean> lookupSearchG = getLookUpValList(mainSearchG,mainSearchV); 
    final List<LookUpValueBean> daysOutG= getLookUpList(daysOutstanding); 
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(); 
    final ReportListDTO reportListDTO= new ReportListDTO(); 
    List<ReportListDTO> reportList= new ArrayList<ReportListDTO>(); 
    mav.addObject("lookupSearchG", lookupSearchG); 
    mav.addObject("daysOutG", daysOutG); 
    mav.addObject(ApplicationConstants.GENERAL_REPORT_COMMAND,reportListDTO); 
    mav.addObject(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_SEARCH_ADD,reportSearch); 
    try{ 
        validator.validate(reportSearch, result); 
        if(reportSearch.getMainSearch().equalsIgnoreCase("CREATED ON")&&!"".equals(reportSearch.getCreatedOnDate())){ 
            reportValidator.validate(reportSearch, result); 
        } 
        if(result.hasErrors()){ 
            // NOT COVERED BY COBERTURA
            mav.addObject("lookupSearchG", lookupSearchG); 
            mav.addObject("daysOutG", daysOutG); 
            mav.setViewName(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_GENERAL_VIEW);         
        } else{ 
            reportList = reportService.searchGeneralReport(reportSearch); 
            mav.addObject("reportList", reportList); 
        } 
    } catch(COBException e){ 
        // not covered
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(),e); 
    } 
    mav.setViewName(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_GENERAL_VIEW); 
    return mav; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before I go into details, it is worth pointing out that achieving 100% coverage is not a worthwhile goal.  Instead, you should be aiming for good coverage of the code that matters.  Coverage is less important for code sections where the chance of an unseen error is low is; e.g. when the code is so simple that a one-time visual inspection will suffice<sup>*</sup>.

(Also, 100% coverage by itself is no guarantee of adequate testing.)

---

The first example is marginally useful.  It looks like the exception will only be thrown if either your SQL is incorrect or if you supply a deliberately a bad record.  Given the nature of the code, I'd give this one a miss.  (But if you really want to, you could mock `sqlMapClientTemplate` with an object that gives you some bad SQL ... for example.)

The second example is worth covering.  You should be able to trigger it by passing a `reportSearch` that fails one of the validations.

The third example is not worth covering.  You can tell the code is correct by inspection.  (But injecting bad SQL as in the first example should work.)

---

<sup>* There is a flaw in this argument.  Someone may replace some untested lines that are "obviously correct" with others that are not.  So I guess there needs to be a code inspection tool that can be used "check off" the untested code sections ... and notice when the code has changed since the last inspection.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to use mocks in your unit tests to simulate these exceptional cases.

### To test the First Bit of Code

In your unit test, inject a mock of `sqlMapClientTemplate` that throws `DataAccessException` when `queryForList` is called.  Your test should check that `COBException` in this case

### To test the second bit of code

Two new tests

- Pass in a `BindingResult` that returns true for `hasErrors()` and then check that the `ModelAndView` has what you expect in it
- Inject a mock of `reportSearch` that generates a `COBException`.  Not sure how to check what happened to assert something, but you could get coverage that way.